# How to disable muliple radio button (under same group) in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

In my case when page loads I want to disable row of radio buttons with same group
in check box checks under same group radio buttons will get enable,

My code is like

```
 <tr *ngFor="let p of c .permission">
                <td><label class="font-light">
                    <input class="minimal-red" type="checkbox"
                         name="{{p.permissionid}}"
                           (change)="getPermission(p, $event)">
                    {{ p.permissionname}} </label></td>

                       <td><label class="font-light">
                        <input class="minimal-red" type="radio" value="self" name="{{p.permissionname}}"
                           [disabled]="disableRole(p.permissionname)">self</label></td>
                      <td><label class="font-light">
                        <input class="minimal-red" type="radio" value="selfrole"   name="{{p.permissionname}}" [disabled]="disableRole(p.permissionname)">self Role </label></td>
```

I want to disable row of radio buttons in page load, in check box check I want to able the radio buttons,Please help me how to do?

Comment: how `(change)="getPermission(p, $event)"` looks like for now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a public flag in your class to disable it at page load like:

```
public p.permissionname = true;
```

Now in your page you will get a disabled radio when you change to this:

```
[disabled]="p.permissionname"
```

Now at the checkbox bound event you can set it to false:

```
<input class="minimal-red" type="checkbox"
       name="p.permissionid"
       (change)="getPermission(p, $event)">

getPermission(p, ev){
   // some other code;

   this.p.permissionname = !this.p.permissionname; // will toggle the state
}
```

#### [Demo @Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fE8ukqUcd704Sy9pUoph?p=preview)